# How do I use multiple bib files with TexStudio?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, texstudio

My project uses multiple bib files: `a.bib` and `b.bib`. In order to compile the document, I need to `pdflatex` first, then `bibtex` on the `aux` files generated from those two individual `bib` files, and then `pdflatex` twice at the end. TexStudio does not seem to be able to run `bibtex` on the generated `aux` files. However, when my project used to use a single `bib` file, TexStudio used to work flawlessly. How can I fix it?

Comment: Write the following in the first line of the main tex file: `% !TEX TS-program = latexmk -pdf -silent -synctex=1 %  | txs:///view`. Maybe that's how it works.

Comment: As suggested, use a proper build tool like latexmk or arara.

Comment: What's wrong with TexStudio?

Comment: @sherlock No problem with TeXstudio. Write the following in the first line of the main tex file: `% !TEX TS-program = latexmk -pdf -silent -synctex=1 %  | txs:///view` and push F5. Then the default compiler tool will be latexmk in the TeXstudio, which handles your problem.

Comment: Thanks, it worked

Answer (score 3):

Multiple `.bib` files do not per se require multiple BibTeX runs.

The following example document looks alright after running pdfLaTeX, BibTeX, pdfLaTeX, pdfLaTeX only on the basename of the `.tex` file.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-a.bib}
@book{elk,
  author    = {Anne Elk},
  title     = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year      = {1972},
  publisher = {Monthy \& Co.},
  location  = {London},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-b.bib}
@book{belk,
  author    = {Anne Belk},
  title     = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year      = {1973},
  publisher = {Monthy \& Co.},
  location  = {London},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname-a.bib}
\addbibresource{\jobname-b.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{belk,elk}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

With `biblatex` and `backend=bibtex,` you'll start requiring multiple BibTeX runs once you start using `refsection`s and other advanced features that essentially require generating separate bibliographies. This is, however, independent of the number of `.bib` files you are using (and you will usually run BibTeX on files with names derived from the basename of your `.tex` file and not on any `.bib` files).

If you use `backend=biber,` as recommended with `biblatex` you will only need to call Biber on the base name of the main `.tex` file even if you use advanced features like `refsection`s. It is not necessary to run Biber on different files. The only thing that might be required in exceptional circumstances are longer compile sequences of the form LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX.

This answer was written from a `biblatex` perspective, but it still holds from a classical BibTeX perspective. Multiple `.bib` files do not require running BibTeX on multiple files. Multiple bibliographies like those courtesy of [`bibtopic`](https://ctan.org/pkg/bibtopic) and friends might do.

---

As far as I know TeXStudio has some limited support to automatically run LaTeX and BibTeX/Biber for you when required, but at least for me this heuristic does not always get things right and I can believe that it does not support things like calling BibTeX on multiple files out of the box. If you can consistently reproduce TeXstudio's reluctance to run BibTeX as required for your document, you can open an issue at https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues to request support for multiple BibTeX runs.

For advanced one-stop build control you may want to have a look at [`latexmk`](https://ctan.org/pkg/latexmk) or [`arara`](https://ctan.org/pkg/arara).

Comment: You are right. I am using biblatex with bibtex backend and two refesections coming from two separate bib files